# How to debug windows device driver and what to debug if driver is installed on VM?

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, device-driver

I'm using VS 2012 and VM on same machine.
Host Win7_x64 and VM on same machine is again Win7_x64
Debug using VS 2012, i.e using VS and pipe serial connection on VM.

Everything is proper. I'm able to load driver on VM using VS's in built process to attach.
I've build, link and install KmdfSmall driver given on microsoft website onto VM
I've build, link and install another very small test driver onto VM.
Yes, all drivers are showing very properly into device manager of VM.

When ever I'm pressing break all onto host in debug mode into VS; all break points are also becoming read on .c and .cpp files.
But the question comes here when I pressed f10 for checking code flow "No Source Code Available " window is getting open.

Actually I'm not very much familiar that how and where it should go but as in normal C program case in VS during debug the pointer go ahead in source file so here in window device driver where it should go.

thus how to debug driver here and what should I check to understand that driver is installed properly and working fine.

Attaching few images to get better idea. It will let you know that how much I reached.
Here I'm trying to debug NOTHING driver of OSR online

http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=390

Kindly guide me to the best direction of what to debug and how in this windows device driver.

One image is of host having VS and another image is of VM where driver has been installed.
Please help me to debug the driver and understand its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On target, disable the driver meanwhile keep the VS into running debug mode onto host.
Then restart the target, enable the driver as soon as enable the driver onto target
it will jump to VS running into debug mode onto host at the already settled breakpoint. then after just press F5 and go ahead.

regards
matt